# Streaming with crtmpserver and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I'm trying to use crtmpserver and ffmpeg (from the mc3man ppa, i'm on ubuntu 14.04) to stream, for now just locally on my machine (to get everything working).

I have the default crtmpserver setup, and it is running.

Now, i try to stream a flv file using:

```
ffmpeg -re -i SampleVideo_1280x720_20mb.flv  -f flv -c copy -metadata streamName="aaa" "tcp://localhost:6666"
```

and then, while it is playing, watch the result with ffplay

```
ffplay "rtmp://localhost/flvplayback/aaa"
```

However, this last command results in the following errors:

```
[rtmp @ 0x7f7800005760] Server error: call to function _checkbw failed
rtmp://localhost/flvplayback/aaa: Unknown error occurred
```

Im unsure what im doing wrong, does anybody with more experience with this have any ideas as to what i could try to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I have used crtmpserver thoroughly  , I know that _checkbw error . Although I dont know how to fix that yet but you can alternatively used the following ffmpeg command st stream to crtmpserver on rtsp and play it back from any media player including VLC and  android native media player .

```
ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 20 -c:v libx264 -q 1 -f rtsp -metadata title="aaa" "tcp://<server ip here>:5554"
```

also you can play it back via

```
vlc rtsp://<server ip here>:5554/flvplayback/aaa
```

PS : Be sure to allow traffic for these ports on the server .